# pork went over internal temperature, can I make it tender by putting the oven in a lower temperature for a couple of hours?

Tags: oven, temperature, pork, overcooking

I cooked a piece of pork shoulder and i put it at 250 celcius for 30 min and 130 celcius for 1 hours. Now the internal temperature is well above the 71 celcius mark and the meat looks tough. If i put the oven at a lower temperature can the meat soften up and make it tender?

Comment: There's a similar question on here asking for advice on how to deal with a roast (might not have been pork) that came out tough. ... but I'm having no luck in finding it.  (I think I answered that you should cut it (across the grain), and then give it a slow braise ... so basically what you suggested, but with slicing, too)

Answer (score 2):

Your pork will not become tender for quite a while. If you plan to shred it, you'll want to aim for about 205 degrees F / 96 degrees C.

You don't have to go that high if your goal is to slice.

Either way, a cut like pork shoulder is best cooked low and slow to allow all of the marbled fat to break down. It's an incredibly resilient cut of meat, but it requires patience.

While it is technically "done" as in safe to eat, it's not reached its culinary potential.

Comment: +1 this... pork shoulder should have a minimum of 6-8 hours on a low heat. I typically cook (smoke) mine for 12+ hours. If you don't have that kind of time/patience, try the shorter time, wrapping the meat in foil halfway through, and letting it rest wrapped in foil for 30min+ after done.

Answer (score 0):

The toughness is caused by shrinking the connective tissue in the muscle with heat.  There is nothing you can do, post cooking, to make it tender. About the only thing you can do is shred it.